# Use value of radiobutton across classes

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a tkinter window and I created radiobuttons in one of my classes. I want to use the value of my radiobutton in another class but I get "choice" not defined.

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):        

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        var = tk.IntVar()

        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Herfindahl Index", variable=var, 
        value=1).place(relx=0.3, rely=0.3, anchor="w")

        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Crop Diversification Index", variable=var, 
        value=2).place(relx=0.3, rely=0.4, anchor="w")

        choice = var.get()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):        

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        if choice==1:
            button6 = ttk.Button(self, text=str(choice), 
            command=herfindahl_index)
            button6.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
```

Comment: How do you invoke PageOne inside PageTwo?

Comment: `choice` is a local variable that only exists inside the `PageOne.__init__()` method and its value is likely `None` or `''` because executing `choice = var.get()` there is not correct.